# How to pop custom modal on a:href?

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to web coding, and I've been trying to make the custom modal show up clicking "About", but it simply doesn't happen, and I really have no clue of why, anyone knows? I put my full website, including CSS, because I simply don't know what's compatible and what's not compatible with bootstrap modal.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
  <title>Documento senza titolo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="Senza titolo-1.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="abovenavigation">
      <ul class="container">
        <li>
          <h1 class="About"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ABOUT</a></h1>
        </li>
      </ul><!--ends container-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-="" dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle setup?

Comment: Ok there u have the snippet now

Comment: I've changet it all, and I put my attempt as well, just to show you that it's not working the way I'm doing it, but I really have no clue of why, it seems fine to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to read up on the manual for modals. The easiest way is giving your `<a id="btn-show-modal">` a few extra attributes, namely `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#dialog-example"`. Next, you're missing a few divs in your modal's structure:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="dialog-example">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1>Hi! Do You Want To Join My Fun English Course? Here's What You Need to Know!</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <pre>Cost Per Lesson: 10€; Hours Per Lesson: 1,30h; Days a Week: Monday to Thursday;</pre>    
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice the `modal-dialog` and `modal-content`; both were missing from your markup and causing weird behaviors. Also, I'm not sure what `modal hide` is. Please read here for more information: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Live Demo: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/jSnxSFemK3)

Comment: I followed this tutorial on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXgI8y0d4LU.. I don't know why, I can see it works on your feedle, but it doesn't work on my website! It's been days that I try to figure out, and I am not easy to give up, could it be that something is missing in my website?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u221vjz3/ here's my full website, as u can see it does not work

Comment: Now i even tried using the custom modal, but it wont show up, I just don't know, I followed the instructions on bootstrap website..